# Javascript Flowchart designer in style of CKeditor

Tags: javascript, xml, textarea, wysiwyg, flowchart

I've learned here, on stack overflow, that what I need is called "flow-chart". I need to allow user to draw in a browser (using his mouse) a flow-chart that would represent a flow of a process or an algorithm. This flow-chart should contain decisions (yes/no diamonds), tasks (rectangles), arrows, labels etc.

Flow-chart editor should be a part of a Form on a web page, should be written in JavaScript and important is, that it must produce a text output (XML?) that will be storable in DB and when this page is opened again, chart will be rendered based on the previously save text.

No other outputs wil be necessary. Essentially, what I need is just a graphical XML editor/creator.

It would be perfect if it worked as same as CkEditor:
http://ckeditor.com/demo

This CkEditor is a JS Html editor that covers a textarea (in a form) and when you write something in this editor, it is (on the background) converted into HTML and written into the textarea. When you send the whole form using a button, the content of textarea can be processed and saved.

I read following thread, but nothing was suitable for my purposes

stackoverflow.com/questions/363592/javascript-library-for-hierarchical-flowchart

Very close to my idea was this project, but it is a Java program that is run outside of browser and output can not be stored in DB.

www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html

Did anyone use something like I just described?

**Update 1: This could be what i was loking for.** Does anybody know something similar and/or free?
origramy.com/origramy.html

Comment: I know this is old, but the origramy link you sent is a Flash editor, not JavaScript/HTML.  I think it would be particularly hard to get this working across all browsers and without breaking in future browsers.

Comment: In terms of the JGraph link, you have the wrong product there. JGraph is for Java, mxGraph, http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html is the JavaScript browser implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You will find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558972/javascript-flowchart-library-for-workflow-visualization) thread useful. It talks about generating flowchart from BPMN which is in XML.